# Why Requests and Secure Requests Quota has been increased in google app engine?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, gae-quotas

When I use the request URL as `http://myapp.appspot.com` quota use increases only for `Quota Details --> Requests`.

But When I use the request URL as `https://myapp.appspot.com` quota use increases for both `Quota Details --> Requests` and `Quota Details --> Secure Requests`.

When I use the request `https` URL, why do both `Requests` and `Secure Requests` quota usage increase.

Can you give me a reason for this and any ways to solve it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [quotas page](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/quotas?hl=sv-SE#Requests) states:

```
Secure Outgoing Bandwidth:
The amount of data sent by the application over a secure connection in response 
to requests. Secure outgoing bandwidth also counts toward the Outgoing Bandwidth 
quota.
```

Comment: Thanks. I am using secure URL. Why increasing Request Quota also.

Comment: Because secure traffic counts also toward the total traffic.